# How to Override a Virtual method with Object type in the parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I want to override BuildFilter Method in the derived class. I have a virual BuildFilter Method with the following signatures

```
 public abstract class BaseSearchProperty <TEntity> : ISearchResultProperty<TEntity>

 {       
    public virtual List<AppliedFilter> BuildFilter(object value)
    {
        return new List<AppliedFilter>();
    }

  }
```

i know the BuildFilter method override types one is `string` and another one is a List of String `List<string>`. i have written the override methods in the derived class as below

```
public class IndustrySearchProperty : BaseSearchProperty<API.ISearchResult>
{
    public override List<AppliedFilter> BuildFilter(string filterValue,)
    {
        var appliedFilters = new List<AppliedFilter>();

        return appliedFilters;
    }

    public override List<AppliedFilter> BuildFilter(List<string> filterValue)
    {
        var appliedFilters = new List<AppliedFilter>();

        return appliedFilters;
    }
}
```

but am getting error like no suitable method found to override. I know what this error is both parent class signature and child class signature needs to be same. Is there any other way that i solve this problem??

Answer (score 1):

> both parent class signature and child class signature needs to be same

Yes. There is no clean way.

Two things you can do:

1. Get the object in the overrided method and cast to whatever type needed or
2. Add a new type parameter

like this:

```
public abstract class BaseSearchProperty <TEntity,TFilter> : ISearchResultProperty<TEntity>
{       
    public virtual List<AppliedFilter> BuildFilter(TFilter value)
    {
        return new List<AppliedFilter>();
    }
}
```

I recommend neither. This is a code smell in my mind showing you are not using inheritance correctly. And it probably doesn't support Liskov and other principles.